# How do I make 3D (densityPlot) and 4D (densityPlot3D) plots from data in excel file?

Tags: import, plotting

I have data from an experiment with about 500 rows and five columms. I have learnt from this forum how to import my data with the code.

importeddata = Import["sample.xlsx"][[1]];
Grid[importeddata]

My problem now is that I wish to make 3D (ListdensityPlot) and 4D (ListdensityPlot3D) plots from these data in which I can select the columns to be plotted against one another. That is, I can specify 3 columns to be used for 3D and four columns to be used for 4D within the code. Secondly, I want the selected column headings be automatically labeled across the axes and my last selected column be colored legends by the right hand side of the plots. I actually have a code but it is too poor to be shown here. I would be deeply grateful for your opinions and suggestions. Thanks.

EDITS: Please see my data below (reduced to just 16 rows) [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/byqtfjrfmikk73k/forcemap.xlsx?dl=0)!.
I want to be able to select either Force or Power to be plotted against Time vs (a) either x or y for 3D (b)  x and y for 4D. Thanks once more!

Comment: Can you upload your data to see the result?

Comment: Thank you Alex, I have edited my question as you have recommended.

Comment: Dean, this is not data, it's a picture. Upload your data in the original format. We must see the result of the code.

Comment: Hi Alex, I have made necessary modifications to my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = {{0, 93, 84, 55, 99}, {10, 58, 85, 70, 79}, {20, 30, 60, 95, 
    95}, {32, 29, 78, 22, 70}, {33, 6, 97, 21, 46}, {43, 24, 39, 13, 
    13}, {50, 94, 12, 93, 76}, {51, 1, 26, 44, 74}, {51, 15, 79, 64, 
    2}, {57, 43, 23, 71, 67}, {59, 93, 17, 2, 17}, {69, 8, 79, 13, 
    6}, {70, 76, 98, 51, 67}, {71, 79, 85, 54, 64}, {73, 93, 16, 79, 
    80}};

Legended[ListDensityPlot[data[[All, {1, 2, 4}]], 
  FrameLabel -> {"Time", "x"}, ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors"], 
 Placed[BarLegend[{"ThermometerColors", MinMax@data[[All, 4]]}, 
   LegendLabel -> 
    Placed["Force (N) ", Right, Rotate[#, 90 Degree] &]], Right]]
```

[image]

```
Legended[ListDensityPlot3D[data[[All, {1, 2, 3, 4}]], 
  AxesLabel -> {"Time", "x", "y"}, 
  ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors"], 
 Placed[BarLegend[{"ThermometerColors", MinMax@data[[All, 4]]}, 
   LegendLabel -> 
    Placed["Force (N) ", Right, Rotate[#, 90 Degree] &]], Right]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, Okkes Dulgerci. The codes worked excellently. My problem is now solved!

Comment: My pleasure! You can accept it by clicking accept.

Comment: Done! Thanks once again.

Answer (score 2):

Using data from your Excel sample file, we select columns for `ListDensityPlot` and `ListDensityPlot3D`. The plots are automatically labeled for the columns we select.

```
data = {{"Time{s}", "x(m)", "y(m)", "Force(N)", "Power(W)"}, {0, 93, 
    84, 55, 99}, {10, 58, 85, 70, 79}, {20, 30, 60, 95, 95}, {32, 29, 
    78, 22, 70}, {33, 6, 97, 21, 46}, {43, 24, 39, 13, 13}, {50, 94, 
    12, 93, 76}, {51, 1, 26, 44, 74}, {51, 15, 79, 64, 2}, {57, 43, 
    23, 71, 67}, {59, 93, 17, 2, 17}, {69, 8, 79, 13, 6}, {70, 76, 98,
     51, 67}, {71, 79, 85, 54, 64}, {73, 93, 16, 79, 80}};
```

Choose the columns to plot. For example, use:

```
select2D = {1, 2, 4}; (*time,x,force*)
```

or

```
select2D = {1, 3, 5}; (*time,y,power*)
```

Automatically select labels and display with `ListDensityPlot`.

```
lbls = First[data][[select2D]];

ListDensityPlot[Rest[data[[All, select2D]]], FrameLabel -> Most@lbls, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, LegendLabel -> Last@lbls], {After, 
    Top}]]
```

[image: ListDensityPlot]

The method is similar for `ListDensityPlot3D` - we select columns to plot:

```
select3D = {1, 2, 3, 4};(*time,x,y,force*)
```

or

```
select3D = {1, 2, 3, 5};(*time,x,y,power*)
```

Automatically select labels and display with `ListDensityPlot3D`.

```
lbls = First[data][[select3D]];

ListDensityPlot3D[Rest@data[[All, select3D]], AxesLabel -> Most@lbls, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, LegendLabel -> Placed[Last@lbls, Top]], 
   Right]]
```

[image: ListDensityPlot3D]

Comment: Thank you so much, creidhne. The modular presentation of your response is quite good. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your data is not smooth, however,
is this what you are looking for?:

```
    importeddata =Import["forcemap.xlsx"][[1]];Grid[importeddata]
    xt = Table[{importeddata[[i,1]], importeddata[[i,2]]}, 
    {i,2,Length[importeddata[[All, 2]]]}];

    (* {{0., 93.}, {10., 58.}, {20., 30.}, {32., 29.}, {33., 6.}, {43., 
    24.}, {50., 94.}, {51., 1.}, {51., 15.}, {57., 43.}, {59., 
    93.}, {69., 8.}, {70., 76.}, {71., 79.}, {73., 93.}} *)

    ListPlot[xt, Joined -> True]

    (* the plot of x vs t *)

    fxy = Table[{importeddata[[i, 2]], importeddata[[i, 3]], 
    importeddata[[i, 4]]}, {i, 2, Length[importeddata[[All, 2]]]}];
    ListPlot3D[fxy]

    (*the plot of the force vs x and y*)
```

For any other plot just select the column in the second coordinate of "importeddata".

Comment: Thanks Gluoncito!!